# Multiple fetch Promises - same url, different body

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

Trying multiple `fetch` Promises to the same URL, but with a different body to each call. Currently I'm writing them all out. How would I go about writing this in a less verbose fashion?

```js
Promise.all([
    fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myurl.com/verify", {
      body: `link=${productVariant1}&license_key=${licenseKey}`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      method: "POST"
    }).then(do something),
    fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myurl.com/verify", {
      body: `link=${productVariant2}&license_key=${licenseKey}`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      },
      method: "POST"
    }).then(do something),
  ]).then(data => {

      /* process response */
    }
```

There's 5 Promises in total, with only the `productVariant` part of the call being different.

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: The question is how would I write this in a less verbose way?

Comment: Add a helper function with `url` and `body` parameters and call each time

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is to make your api robust and have it support multiple args in once for example a single call with `body: link=${productVariant1},${productVariant2}` and so on and the api can read it in respond accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do it with map:

```
Promise.all([productVariant1, productVariant2].map((productVariant, i) => {
return fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myurl.com/verify", {
          body: `link=${productVariant}&license_key=${licenseKey}`,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          },
          method: "POST"
        }).then(data => console.log(`Promise ${i} done`))
})
).then(data => {
console.log("all promises done")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function:

```js
function Fetch(body) {
  return fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myurl.com/verify", {
    body,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    method: "POST"
  }).then(doSomething)
}

// And then

Promise.all([
  Fetch(`link=${productVariant2}&license_key=${licenseKey}`),
  Fetch(`link=${productVariant2}&license_key=${licenseKey}`)
]).then(responses => {
  // do something with responses
})
```

Or if the **only** thing you're changing